# Symfony: Clear doctrine cache

Tags: php, caching, symfony, doctrine

I need to clear my [doctrine's](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) cache in [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).

There must be some way in command line for *clear the cache*.

Or where should I find and delete the files belonging to cache?

Comment: `rm -rf app/cache/*` didn't help?

Comment: does the answer helps? if no, try clearing complete cache using app/console cache:clear

Comment: @thecatontheflat - note that the doctrine cache is often stored in apc rather than in the file system so removing the cache files would not help.

Comment: @amitchhajer - note that the general `app/console cache:clear` is only for the symfony (app) cache. I don't think it clears the doctrine cache(s).

Answer (score 143, accepted):

For Symfony 3+:

```
 php bin/console
```

will list all commands, the following are relevant for cache:

```
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

---

Before Symfony 3:

```
app/console
```

will list how you can do it

```
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

Comment: By the way, if you are using mongodb for example you can do 'app/console doctrine:mongodb:cache:clear-metadata' or just do 'app/console doctrine' and you will see all available options

Comment: Note that you can always use `app/console list` to show all commands or `app/console list doctrine` to just show commands in the 'doctrine' namespace

Comment: I tried `doctrine:cache:clear-result` in prod environment. It is not working. I also tried `bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:result`. It doesn't work either. I'm using `memcache`.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it within your code (from [Doctrine's documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#all)) :

> If you simply want to delete all cache entries you can do so with the
> deleteAll() method.
>
> ```
> $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
> $deleted = $cacheDriver->deleteAll();
> ```

Comment: What's the difference to cache flushing?

Comment: This code creates a new cache driver. It should utilize the current QueryCacheProfile or result cache implementation from the configuration. It will not magically clear cache in your application if use use e.g. Redis or Memcached.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use APC, you could also just call the code

```
<?php
$deleted = apc_clear_cache() && apc_clear_cache('user');
```

in a php page on the same server. This is what deleteAll() method in Antho's answer does, but you do not depend on the Doctrine Classes. Btw: the complete cache will be flushed - just in case you use it for non-Doctrine stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I was going crazy with doctrine results caching - in the end I had to restart memcached.

Comment: how to restart memcached?

Answer (score 1):

I know the title of this post says Symfony 2, but for those of you coming from google, if you have Symfony 3+ its gonna be:

```
bin/console
```

As opposed to:

```
app/console
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a little late for this, but in my case, doctrine didn't generate the proxy classes in production, for that I change the `auto_generate_proxy_classes` to true:

```
#symfony2&3 app/config/config.yml
#symfony4 config/packages/doctrine.yaml (by default true since 4.2)

doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true #"%kernel.debug%"
```

Comment: What do these proxy classes do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone searching
Symfony 6.2+

```
public function __construct(..., private KernelInterface $kernel
```

And

```
$this->kernel->shutdown(); //RESET ALL
```

You running Multiple entities and You managed connection with Sessions

```
/** @var SiteService $siteService */
$siteService = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get(SiteService::class); //Important kernel->getContainer()
/** @var Site[] $sites */
$sites = $siteService->repository->getByInstalledSites();

foreach ($sites as $site) {
    dump('Domain:'. $site->getDomain());
    $session = new Session();
    $session->set('db_user', $site->getUser());
    $session->set('db_password', $this->getDecryptPassword($site->getPassword()));
    $session->set('db_name', $site->getDatabaseName())
    
    $user = $this->userService->getById(1);

    dump($user);
    //what you want to do ...

    $this->kernel->shutdown(); //Running All bundles shutdown and container set null        
    $this->kernel->boot(); // services_resetter->reset and preboot -> loading bundles&Containers and all bundles set container & run boot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the hopes that this might help someone coming here with Doctrine caching issues.

I had an issue with the OrderBy attribute and the PostLoad event not seeming to fire. The problem was that the entity was already loaded into the EntityManager (from when I created it). Because it was already loaded, subsequent calls to get it went to memory/cache and the expected events wouldn't get fired.

To fix, you can clear the entity out of the EntityManager. Then when you get the entity, the PostLoad callback, OrderBy, etc will fire. You can clear the entity out of the EntityManager like so:

```
$this->em->clear(MyEntity::class);
```