# Symfony2 custom repository class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository, entity

I am new to symfony2 and I am trying to create custom repository class and couldn' do it.

Here is what I am doing:

- I added annotation to entity class ( MobilePhones )

> @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Maak\DefaultBundle\Entity\MobilePhonesRepository")

- In MobilePhonesRepository I created my custom function named `findAllMobilePhones()`
- In controller I called function using:

> $em->getRepository('MaakDefaultBundle:MobilePhones')->findAllMobilePhones();

but I get `Undefined method findAllMobilePhones()`, I have cleared cache and tried but same error. What is wrong?

**My repository class:**

```
<?php

namespace Maak\DefaultBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MobilePhonesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllMobilePhones()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC') ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `echo get_class($em->getRepository('MaakDefaultBundle:MobilePhones'))` return? Can you also provide the classfile for MobilePhonesRepository?

Comment: It returns Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

Comment: <?php

namespace Maak\DefaultBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MobilePhonesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllMobilePhones()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC')
                    ->getResult();
    }
}

Comment: This is actually Doctrine 2 related, so you should tag your question with `doctrine2` to get max exposure. Also can you put your Repository code in the question so it's easily readable.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have cleared the metadata cache? Your annotation is looking good and if `customRepositoryName` is set in your metadata there will be an exception if it cannot be instanciated correctly. If it is still not working put a `var_dump($metadata)` in the [EntityManager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php) on line 750 and show us the output.

Comment: Try: $em->getRepository('Maak\DefaultBundle\Entity\MobilePhones')->findAllMobilePhones(); It's possible your bundle name is wrong or things are not configured quite right.

Comment: @Bram : Yes I have cleared metadata cache. I have dumped metadata and it is not setting customRepositoryClassName.<br/>@Cerad : I have tried and it's not working either.

Comment: @KhalidMushtaq, try putting some `var_dump` in the [AnnotationDriver](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php), in particular line 78. If you clear or disable the cache `loadMetadataForClass()` must be executed.

Comment: @BramGerritsen, I have cleared cache and placed var_dump in the AnnotationDriver but it is not being executed.

Comment: @KhalidMushtaq, I'm pretty sure your metadata is still loaded from the cache. You really should **disable** all caching first, instead of invalidating it.

Comment: @BramGerritsen, I have disabled $kernel->loadClassCache() and I'm already using app_dev.php but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @KhalidMushtaq, I'm afraid I can't help you any further because I am not a Symfony user. `loadClassCache()` sounds like classmap caching to me so that has nothing to do with Doctrine cache anyway. You tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826444/symfony2-doctrine-clear-cache).

Comment: @BramGerritsen, Thanks for your time. Yes I have done it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all guys for their time. Finally I have found the issue.

I decided to debug whole project and found `repository-class` was not being set in XMLDriver that was going to set `customRepositoryName` in metadata. It was because I was using XML mappings and for this entity I was providing `repositoryClass` using Annotations.

Thank again :)