# How to create custom repository in symfony2

Tags: symfony

User Entity :

```
namespace Core\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Core\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
}
```

User Repository :

```
<?php 
# src/Core/UserBundle/Entity/UserRepository.php

namespace Core\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function example()
    {
        return "hello word";
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository('CoreUserBundle:User');
$repo->example();
```

Note : `get_class($repo) => Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`

The error:

```
Error Message : Undefined method 'example'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

Comment: have you tried cache:clear?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176424/symfony2-custom-repository-class

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

$repo = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User');