# Symfony2 doesn't seem to recognize my repository class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am encountering the error **Undefined method 'findAllCtrs'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!**

I've tried all the other solutions on StackOverflow regarding this problem. I've cleared cache, cleared meta data cache, checked the namespaces and folder entities but still no fix.

Here is my entity:

```
namespace CFS\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ref
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ref", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="refno", columns={"refno"}), @ORM\Index(name="ctrno", columns={"ctrno"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CFS\Bundle\Entity\RefRepository")
 */
 class Ref
{
```

My repository class:

```
namespace CFS\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class RefRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function findAllCtrs()
  {
     $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT
                r.refno, r.ctrno
            FROM
                CFSBundle:Ref r
            ORDER BY
                r.refno DESC
            ');

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

And I tried calling the method in my controller with:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $containers = $em->getRepository('CFSBundle:Ref')
            ->findAllCtrs();
```

I did noticed that when I generate entities in the command line `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities CFSBundle` it is not recognizing my RefRepository.php file. What else could I have missed?

Comment: Any chance that you have a Resources\config\doctrine\Ref.orm.yml file hanging around?

Comment: @Cerad, yes, what should I be looking for?

Comment: @Cerad, it's actually an xml instead of a .yml

Comment: @Cerad, Oh I see. Annotations cannot be mixing with other formats. Deleted the .xml's and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stuck with a similar error too, after spending a day searching for a solution I found a typo in my annotation referencing the repository class.
But I don't see a mistake in the code you provided, hence it should work…

Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184084/1781752 ?
There seemed to be problems mixing yml mappings and annotations.

Comment: You are correct! It was a problem of mixing of annotations and other formats.