# Symfony: Property does not exist - 500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I removed `$hearAboutIndustry` from the entity and now getting error below only in production server, not on local and staging server! Any idea why or solution?

```
Property Tete\AdminBundle\Entity\Customer::$hearAboutIndustry does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException
```

config_prod.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

What I have do to solve it so far:

- Removed getter and setters from the entity.
- Deleted whole cache and logs folders and re-created back, inc 777.
- Just in case run `cache:clear --env=prod`
- Searched `hearAboutIndustry` in all directories/files of the project. No reference at all.
- Run `doctrine:schema:update`. DB is updated.
- Run `doctrine:generate:entities`. Entity is updated.
- app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
- app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
- app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result

Comment: Do you use APC caching or any other caching with Doctrine? One way to tell is if doctrine.orm.metadata_cache_driver and doctrine.orm.query_cache_driver are set in config.yml

Comment: Yes I do. I think it is to do wit it. I'm on Ubuntu AWS.

Comment: I applied [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826444/symfony2-doctrine-clear-cache) but no luck.

Comment: Strange. However if you are using APC, one last fix would be to restart Apache or PHP-FPM, depending on which one you use.

Comment: Ahaaa! `sudo apachectl graceful` did the trick. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Adam suggested above in comment, we better restart apache if all the above solutions have been tried and getting no success. The solution is:

`sudo apachectl graceful`

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that worked for you ;) I had a similar problem with using APC for class loading, took me ages to figure it out

Comment: I wasted about 6 hours to sort this out :) Now I can sleep. Thank you again.

Comment: I had the issue where I removed a field off an entity and it kept throwing an error. I tried manually clearing the cache and all that. Restarting apache fixed the issue. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

- php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod

*Clearing ALL Query cache entries*

- php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod

*Clearing ALL Result cache entries*

- php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod

*Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries*

- php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

*Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false*

And don't forget to put --env=prod to your commands

Answer (score 0):

"Old but still happens"
If none of the solutions mentioned above worked
try to delete the Entity cache file manually :
(e.g Entity costumer cache file path should be this one)

projectdirectory\projectname\var\cache{dev or prod}\jms_serializer\Tete-AdminBundle-Entity-Customer.cache.php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I just used doctrine:mapping:import and that was it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and in our case (Nginx), the restart of Nginx didn't help.

But restart of memcache was the right solution:

```
sudo service memcached restart
```