# Symfony/Doctrine: I can query my database but only primary key data is being retrieved

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

So the DQL below works but there is a problem with the records returned. It only displays the primary key data. All other fields are empty/null.

I know my code is communicating fine with my Oracle DB since if I misspelled the table name, it will return with an exception. I also tried it with MySQL (I exported the Oracle table as CSV and imported it into MySQL) and same thing happened. Both Oracle and MySQL tables field definitions are the same.

This is what I get from the Doctrine dump. This is only for a single record. **But the results are the same if I retrieve all records.**

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#64 (5) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(24) "AppBundle\Entity\Student" ["sspnumber"]=> int(71XXXXXX) ["student_id"]=> NULL ["course_appn_year"]=> NULL ["satac_id"]=> NULL } }
```

This is the contents of the record as seen from Oracle (had to hide the info for privacy reasons):

[image]

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks! :)

**Edit1:** If I decide to retrieve just the student_id field, I get "semanctical error" from Symfony. Even though I am 100% the field name spelling is correct.

[image]

**Edit2:** Using Symfony 2.8.8 if this matters. I chose this because I got the impression this is the LTS version.

**Edit3** I always run php app/console cache:clear after synching my sources via gut

**my controller code:**

```
//$myquery = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
//  ->createQuery("SELECT s FROM AppBundle:Student s");

$myquery = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->createQuery("SELECT s FROM AppBundle:Student s WHERE s.sspnumber = :sspnumber")
    ->setParameter("sspnumber", 711XXXXXX);

\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($myquery->getResult());exit();
```

**my entity class**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Student.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

/**
 * @Mapping\Entity
 * @Mapping\Table(name="students")
 */
class Student {
    /**
     * @Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="ssp_no")
     * @Mapping\Id
     * @Mapping\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $sspnumber;

    /*
     * @Mapping\Column(type="string", name="student_id")
     */
    private $student_id;

    /*
     * @Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="course_appn_year")
     */
    private $course_appn_year;

    /*
     * @Mapping\Column(type="string", name="satac_id")
     */
    private $satac_id;
}
```

Comment: do you try simplier way? something like that: $student = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Student')
        ->find('711XXXXXX');

Comment: doctrine caches the proxy that's built from the entity, have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @DanilPyatnitsev I'll try your suggestion tomorrow. Though my  queries will be a bit more complex that searching using SSP_NO. I was only using SSP_NO as a test that my code can speak to the database.

Comment: @RobForrest I always run php app/console cache:clear after synching my sources via git. I guess that clears doctrine cache too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11826487/1886270 - please, clear doctrine cache by using these commands. And I don't known is cache:clear cleared doctrine cache

Comment: I have never dug into the annotation processor but I suspect it might be looking for ORM instead of Mapping.  From a php namespace perspective what you have is correct but if clearing the cache, verifying that you have not generated mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine and calling upon the goddess Hecate does not work then try following the example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

Comment: @Cerad I'll check the resources folder. I didn't know there are generated files there. As form "@ORM", it's "@Mapping" if you don't use an alias (use xxx as yyy). As for the link, I actually used that page (and many others) to construct my Entity class. Thanks again

Comment: As long as you are confident that the Symfony annotation processor is not specifically looking for the string 'ORM' then okay.  I agree with you on the notion of php namespace aliases but the issue here is the annotation reader, not php.  bin/console doctrine:mapping:info might also help.

Comment: I've cleared my doctrine cache multiple times. swapped between Oracle DB and MySQL multiple times. renamed my fieldnames multiple times (changed the name 1 at a time). and somehow it just worked.... :(

Thanks everyone.