# Property does not exist on Symfony 3 Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I cannot get rid of this error when doing `composer update`

> Property AppBundle\Entity\Lander::$landerTokens does not exist

It's a new dir and so there is a minimal cache there. Redis which is also a caching layer has been flushed too.

The term `landerTokens` does not exist anywhere in the code base.

I am using https://deployer.org/ to deploy, so a new dir is created and then everything is run from there during the deployment until everything is OK and a symlink is switched.

Other than flushing Redis and clearing the cache I am not sure what to do.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 doctrine clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826444/symfony2-doctrine-clear-cache)

Answer (score 0):

If the code used to have the '$lander' property in the entity, but it has since been removed - you will have to at least remove the doctrine cache.

[Symfony2 doctrine clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826444/symfony2-doctrine-clear-cache)